# My flash menu going crazy. AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I have a menu with 4 button, for switch to other content page, and all of it had this code:

```
function chuyenhome(e:MouseEvent):void{
    homect.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, nexttohome);
    btn_home.gotoAndStop(15);
    if (btn_about.currentFrame == 15){
    btn_about.gotoAndPlay(16);
    }
    if (btn_menu.currentFrame == 15){
    btn_menu.gotoAndPlay(16);
    }
    if (btn_contact.currentFrame == 15){
    btn_contact.gotoAndPlay(16);
    }
    homect.gotoAndPlay(31);
}
function nexttohome(e:Event):void{
    if (homect.currentFrame>=homect.totalFrames){
        MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(4);
    }
}
```

This is menu HOME. 3 other menu ABOUT, BLOG, CONTACT button is using the same code, but renamed function. It work fine if I click only 2 menu button. But when I try to click the third menu, it's going crazy. For example, when I click at HOME and ABOUT, it switch to HOME page and ABOUT page with no problem, no matter if I click it for thousand times. It work fine, but when I try to click at CONTACT, then... it show up HOME page, I re-click CONTACT, it show up ABOUT... and so on. It's crazy. Sorry about my English. I'm using Flash CS4 and AS3. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to not add multiple event listeners to one MC. See, if all the other functions are this one copypasted with altered frames, then each of them adds an enter frame listener. These are cumulative, thus calling `homect.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, nexttohome);` twice will result in two calls to `nexttohome` per frame. Probably you can avoid this listener altogether by putting code to the timeline of `homect` movie clip on the last frame, to call `stop(); MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(4);`